# Error uploading form xmlhttprequest

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

If I'm using the following javascript,

```
var uploadForm = new FormData();
uploadForm.append("theFile", files[i]);
uploadForm.append("fileName", files[i].name);
var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpReq.open("post", "handleUpload.cfm", true);
httpReq.send(uploadForm);
```

HandleUpload Looks like this :

```
        <cffile  action="upload" 

         destination="uploadedFiles/" 

         accept="image/jpeg, application/pdf, image/png, image/gif" 

         nameconflict="makeunique"

         filefield="theFile" 
    />
```

why would it give me "An exception occurred while trying to read the image." on my corresponding cffile page ?

Comment: Patrick - to know that we will need to see the code for hadnelUpload.cfm - assuming the error is a cf error.

Comment: I should have thought of that... Updating it now...

Comment: I'm going to suggest (i.e. guess) that A) the server side believes it's getting an image file and B) it is instead getting a string or an empty string - hence the error. Use firebug or Chrome dev tools to see the raw request. See what theFile and fileName contain.